# A question inside Newton's Binomial Expansion

Tags: inequality

While proving the Newton's Binomial Expansion, the following inequality has been supposed without proof :

> For each natural number n and any real number $r$, $$0\le (\dfrac{t-x}{1+t})^n (1+t)^{r-1}\le |x|^n\ \text {if}\ -1 <x \le t \le0.$$

How can I prove that?

All I've got is $$0\le \dfrac{t-x}{1+t} \le -x = |x|\ \text {if}\ -1 <x \le t \le0,$$ which won't result in the mentioned inequality (in orange box) esp. when $r<1$.

Thank you.

Comment: Without any other conditions on $r$?  Given $x$, $n$ and $t$ with $-1 < x < t < 0$, you can choose $r$ to make the middle term as large as you want.

Comment: @RobertIsrael - "let r be any number" as in the book! (page 219 - Advanced Calculus by Patrick Fitzpatrick)